# Pattern recognition to draw and match shaped

Tags: image, image-processing, draw

Can anyone kindly point me to any open source program that can draw and match images like the one in [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RPf0KWsrRGk) see 1:10 to 4:20. 
Any clue will be much appreciated. thank you in advance.